# Show more folders in Outlook Web Access for Office 365

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web

I have many folders for organization and I find the most recent version of Outlook Web Access for Office 365 to be clunky when trying to access them.

This is the structure that I have presented to me

### Folders

- Inbox
- Sent Items
- More

It appears that this is a list of the favorites plus a link to the other folders. However, I don't prefer to show my favorites only. How can I show all my folders by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a recent revision has added a pin.

Click the pin to the right of Folders when all are shown.

Comment: Seems like a more recent version got rid of the pin :( Sadly this is no longer an option. Looking for other solutions.

Comment: @TryTryAgain the pinning is gone but i still have my full tree - not under a more option! its much more like desktop outlook now.

Comment: That will allow us to show the folders, but no way to set that expanded view as default. I'm wondering if there is a particular URI/URL string that will do it...